# SP2016 Copy specific records from big list to anther list with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, powershell

I was able to copy all records from a big list to another list but not able to copy specific records form source list to the destination list using PowerShell as below, Any Help Please.

$web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL

$SourceList = $web.Lists[$SourceListName]

$TargetList = $web.Lists[$TargetListName]

$SourceColumns = $sourceList.Fields

#$SourceItems = $SourceList.GetItems();

$souceItems= $SourceList.items | where {$*["created"] -gt '1/1/2015' -and $*["created"] -lt '1/1/2020'};

$souceItems.Count;

Foreach($SourceItem in $SourceItems)

{
$TargetItem = $TargetList.AddItem()

```
Foreach($column in $SourceColumns) 

{
    if($column.ReadOnlyField -eq $False -and $column.InternalName -ne "Attachments")

    {
         $TargetItem[$($column.InternalName)] = $sourceItem[$($column.InternalName)];
    }
}
```

$TargetItem.Update();
}

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Powershell command to:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$SourceList = $web.Lists[$SourceListName]
$TargetList = $web.Lists[$TargetListName]

$SourceColumns = $sourceList.Fields

$caml='<Where>
   <And>
    <Gt>
        <FieldRef Name="Created" />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2015-1-1T12:00:00Z</Value>
    </Gt>
    <Lt>
        <FieldRef Name="Created" />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2020-1-1T12:00:00Z</Value>
    </Lt>
   </And>
   </Where>'
  
$query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.Query=$caml | Write-Output

$SourceItems=$Sourcelist.GetItems($query)

Foreach($SourceItem in $SourceItems)
{
    $TargetItem = $TargetList.AddItem()
    Foreach($column in $SourceColumns) 
    {
        if($column.ReadOnlyField -eq $False -and $column.InternalName -ne 
"Attachments")
        {
             $TargetItem[$($column.InternalName)] = 
$sourceItem[$($column.InternalName)];
        }
    }
   $TargetItem.Update();
}
```

Comment: I get an error when I run the code:                                                                                         The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the collection:
"One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings
page to delete these fields.".
At line:1 char:24
+ Foreach($SourceItem in $SourceItems)
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator

Comment: 1. <FieldRef Name=<replace here with the internal name of your column> />              2. Is your column type Date and Time?

Comment: Yes I did that and tried different columns, yes the column type is Date and Time but still same error.

Comment: Awesome. It worked only when I saved the list as a template and created the Destination List.